# Multiple components in react

Tags: reactjs

Iam new to react .

```
var Ad=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<b>{this.props.name}</b>)
    }
})
var Az=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<b>{this.props.class}</b>)
    }
})
var Aa=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<div>
            <Ad name={this.props.name}/>
            <Az name={this.props.class}/>
            </div>)
    }
})
ReactDOM.render(<Aa name="vijay" class="Asd"/>,document.body)
```

But it is showing only vijay not Asd why? Did react support it to pass two props.

Answer (score 2):

Your component `Az` is expecting property called `class`:

```
return(<b>{this.props.class}</b>)
```

But in your code you are providing only property `name`:

```
<Az name={this.props.class}/>
```

You should change it to be `class` in order to work.

However, there is another issue. `class` is a reserved keyword in React, so you should change `class` to something else in your code, for example `myclass`:

```
// 'class' was changed to 'myclass' in the code below
var Az=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<b>{this.props.myclass}</b>)
    }
})
var Aa=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<div>
            <Ad name={this.props.name}/>
            <Az myclass={this.props.myclass}/>
            </div>)
    }
})
ReactDOM.render(<Aa name="vijay" myclass="Asd"/>,document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never render a component to the body directly. It is a bad practice. Here's why [link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#.r1znz23at)